# Spark- How to read/merge multiple Excel files into a single DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, databricks

There are multiple excel files. (TestFile1.xlsx) (TestFile2.xlsx)(TestFile3.xlsx)

The excel files all share some common columns (Firstname, Lastname, Salary)

How can i get all of these files, with the desired columns only (FirstName,LastName, Salary) into one dataframe?

I use spark in databricks.

Thanks

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: @thebluephantom i have tried using pd.concat to merge the two, but i cant seem to single out the specific columns when using this method. was hoping for an alternative

Comment: why not use pyspark?

Comment: @thebluephantom would sparksql work as well?

Comment: Pyspark has spark sql api as well. Unless u mean %sql on databricks.